# Thin HTTP WebServer on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, thin

I'm currently trying to get Thin webserver running on Windows, to form a basic cluster behind a NGINX proxy, but this is proving to be rather difficult.
I was wondering if anyone actually succeeded in getting this up and running?

To give some examples of the things I have tried:

```
C:\Users\arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2\RubymineProjects\ESCO>thin start
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:926:in `report_activate_error': Rub
yGem version error: thin(1.2.11 not >= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:244:in `activate_dep'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1307:in `gem'
        from C:/Ruby/bin/thin:18:in `<main>'
```

I really don't get this error message. I've included below the environmental output of my system that I'm trying this on (my development system)

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.7.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 180) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - C:/Users/arne.de.herdt.TENFORCE2/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Hoping someone has been experimenting with this.
Also I must say that it's starting to annoy me that the lack for Windows support is such a serious issue with Ruby on Rails. I really enjoy the language and programming in it, but it's a pain getting things to work on Windows machines because of uncompilable dependencies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thin ain't supported under Windows.....